# How to generate XSD from elements of XML

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have a XML input

```
<field>
  <name>id</name>
  <dataType>string</dataType>
  <maxlength>42</maxlength>
  <required>false</required>
</field>
```

I am looking for a library or a tool which will take an XML instance document and output a corresponding XSD schema.

I am looking for some java library with which I can generate a XSD for the above XML structure

Answer (score 14):

If all you want is an XSD so that the XML you gave conforms to it, you'd be much better off by crafting it yourself rather than using a tool.

No one knows better than you the particularities of the schema, such as which valid values are there (for instance, is the `<maxlength>` element required? are `true` and `false` the only valid values for `<required>`?).

If you really want to use a tool (I'd only advice using it if you haven't designed the XML and really can't get the real XSD - or if you designed it, double check the generated XSD), you could try [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html). It can infer an XSD Schema from a number of example XML's.

You'll have to take into account that the XSD a tool can infer you might be incomplete or inaccurate if XML samples aren't representative enough.

```
java -jar trang.jar sampleXML.xml inferredXSD.xsd
```

You can find a [usage example of Trang here](http://www.displayobject.fr/2010/03/08/generate-xsd-from-xml-with-trang/).

Comment: Is there a way to see all the output options for trang ?

Comment: They seem to be well documented at [Trang's official manual](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang-manual.html#output-modules).

Comment: I dont what my xsd to use 'ref' tags or imports. I tried -o disable-abstract-element, but this isn't working !

Answer (score 6):

You can try with online tool called XMLGrid: http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html

Answer (score 2):

You could write an XSLT to do *something* like that. But the problem is, a single document alone is not enough information to generate a schema. Are any of those elements optional? Is there anything missing from that document, that might appear in other instances? How many of a particular element can there be? Do they have to be in that order? There are loads of things that can be expressed in a schema, that are not immediately obvious from one instance of a document that conforms to that schema.

Answer (score 2):

For the people who really want to include it in their Java code to generate an XSD and understand the perils, check out [Generate XSD from XML programatically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314066/generate-xsd-from-xml-programatically-in-java/29707900#29707900)

Answer (score 1):

Try xmlbeans it has some tools one of them is ins2xsd you can find specifics here:
http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html
Good luck

Comment: Welcome to SO! Even though the link in your post provides an answer you have to provide the content in your link. Later the link maybe invalid.