# Generate XSD from XML programmatically in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm looking for a leightweight library that allows me to genereate an XSD from XML in Java (no commandline tool). I know that it is not a clean way to generate it, but in this case I need to do it. Also the XML is very simple in terms of structure.

I already looked into Trang, but there is no API documentation except how to call it from command line.

Also I checked out xsd-gen, but the issue with that library is that one would need to modify some package declrations in the source code which I couldn't find.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am the author of the tool [xsd-gen](https://github.com/wiztools/xsd-gen). I converted the tool to be a library as well, and uploaded the artifact to Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wiztools</groupId>
    <artifactId>xsd-gen</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now it is simple to use as a library within your application:

```
import org.wiztools.xsdgen.XsdGen;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

...

XsdGen gen = new XsdGen();
gen.parse(new File("in.xml"));
File out = new File("out.xsd");
gen.write(new FileOutputStream(out));
```

Comment: Perfect timing - just looking for this :-)

Comment: Very helpful indeed!

Comment: To use this, we also need to add xom jar because it contain nu.xom.parsingException class, if you don't use then it will throw error.

Comment: Small warning - I have found that this does not find all child elements for large xml files.

Answer (score 3):

I included the [xsd-gen source code](https://github.com/wiztools/xsd-gen/tree/master/src/main/java/org/wiztools/xsdgen) and it worked for me. You only need

1. TypeInferenceUtil.java
2. XsdGen.java

The package declarations I used (for Gradle) were:

```
compile("com.io7m.xom:xom:1.2.10")
compile("org.wiztools.commons:wiztools-commons-lib:0.4.1")
```