# How to create XSD to validate XML which was transformed using XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xslt, xsd

What I need is an utility written in Java, which can do the following steps:

1) receives three files from disk (source XML, XSD, XSLT);

2) validates the source XML by XSD;

3) transforms source XML using XSLT;

4) validates the result XML by an appropriate XSD;

5) if anything correct it saves result XML to disk.

I have troubles with the fourth step, I am not an expert in XSD and XMLT so I have no idea how to generate XSD when I have a source XML and XSLT to correctly validate a transformed XML using Java. Please help me with it.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420241/how-to-generate-xsd-from-elements-of-xml

Comment: It makes little sense to generate an XSD automatically from an XML instance and then validate the XML against the generated XSD.  More useful is to validate the XML against a given XSD to make sure that it follows the constraints expressed in the XSD.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, at first I thought the same, but in this case the fourth step turns out a little silly. No sense to generate xsd from xml and then validate it using generated xsd because validation will pass always. May be generating xsd from xmlt and source xml is silly too but such task has more sense, I suppose.